# Passing submit action in adaptive cards on c#

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

How do I parse the submit action value in Adaptive cards? I know am somewhere near but unable to resolve it. If I type a text manually, I move forward to the new dialog in the waterfall model

Cards.json

```
{  
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "id": "textBlock",
      "text": "CREATE AN INCIDENT. "
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "username",
      "placeholder": "Enter your email address"

    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "shortdescription",
      "placeholder": "Enter a short description"

    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Number",
      "id": "phonenumber",
      "placeholder": "Enter your phonenumber"

    }

  ],  
    "actions": [  
        {  
            "type": "Action.Submit",  
            "id": "submit",  
            "title": "Submit",  
            "data":{  
                        "action": "mychoices"  

            }  
        }  
    ],  
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",  
    "version": "1.0"  
}
```

RequestDialog.cs

```
var askforSelectionSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                askForSelection,
                askForSelectionResult,
                CreateTicketFor_InstallSoftware
            };



public async Task<DialogTurnResult> askForSelection(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _state = new GenericRequestState();
            await _accessor.SetAsync(sc.Context, _state);
            //return await sc.PromptAsync(choiceprompt, new PromptOptions()
            //{
            //    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Can you please let me know if the request is for you or someone else?"),
            //    Choices = new List<Choice> { new Choice("MySelf"), new Choice("Someone Else") },
            //    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter MySelf or Someone Else."),
            //});
            return await sc.PromptAsync(TextPrompt, new PromptOptions()
            {
                Prompt = CardHelper.GenericRequestIncidentChoices(sc, cancellationToken),
            });
        }
        public async Task<DialogTurnResult> askForSelectionResult(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var isSuccess = sc.Result.ToString().ToLower();
            if (isSuccess == "incident" || isSuccess == "inc")
            {
                //return await sc.BeginDialogAsync(GenericRequestationStep_OneId);
                return await sc.PromptAsync(TextPrompt, new PromptOptions()
                {
                    Prompt = CardHelper.GenericCreateIncident(sc, cancellationToken),
                });


            }}
```

I have looked into some of the samples and stackoverflow itself but am not able to pass the submit action back to the dialog. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Progressuntilnow]

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override async Task OnEventAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var value = dc.Context.Activity.Value;

        if (value.GetType() == typeof(JObject))
        {
            var result = await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Have you written the JObject handling in OnEventAsync as above?

And Please see the link

[How to retrieve Adaptive Card's form submission in subsequent waterfall step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061325/how-to-retrieve-adaptive-cards-form-submission-in-subsequent-waterfall-step/55066910#55066910)

[ContinueDialogAsync does not work when I use the input form of adaptive-cards in the waterfall dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57284806/continuedialogasync-does-not-work-when-i-use-the-input-form-of-adaptive-cards-in)

Answer (score 0):

Want to know how to handle JToken? If so, see the code below.

```
                var token = JToken.Parse(turnContext.Activity.ChannelData.ToString());
                if (token["postBack"].Value<bool>())
                {
                    JToken commandToken = JToken.Parse(turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString());
                    var data = commandToken["Your_Data_ID"].Value<Your_Data_Type>();
                }
```

"Your_Data_ID" is phonenumber, shortdescription, etc...
Your_Data_Type is int, string, etc...